# Find the last word of the sentence if it is already present before using Regular expression

Tags: python

content = "This is the sentence I have written at Page 1 but I wrote in Page 2"

Ans : = Page 2

```
content = "This is the sentence I have written at Page 1 but I wrote in Page 2"
res1 = re.search("\.?([^\.]*Page[^\.]*)",contents) ---->Search for words after Page
if res1 is not None:
       a = res1.group(1)   
       extracted_page_sequence = re.sub('^(.*)(?=Page)',"", a)  ----->Gets Page 2
       print("Extracted sequence",extracted_page_sequence)
```

If I use this code I am getting **"Page 1 but I wrote in Page 2"** has the solution. Is there any method using regex in Python to get **Page 2** has the solution. In short, need to get last **Page** from the sentence

Comment: "Page 2" is not a word. What's the logic?

Comment: Also what is a "*sentence*"? Is it always the entire content of `a`?

Comment: Sentence which I have given as content and "a" is declaring variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
all_last_occurrences = re.findall("[^\.]*(Page\s+\w+)\s*[^\.]*", content)
```

If `content` is composed by only one sentence like `"This is the sentence I have written at Page 1 but I wrote in Page 2"`, you get the only occurrence at the end of it:

```sh
['Page 2']
```

If `content` contains multiple sentences (each sentence is divided from the next one by a `.`), like in:

```py
content = (
    "This is the sentence I have written at Page 1 but I wrote in Page 2. "
    "This is the sentence I have written at Page 3 but I wrote in Page 4. "
    "This is the sentence I have written at Page 5 but I wrote in Page 6. "
    "Page 7. "
    "ghghPage 8."
    "Page 9 Page 10 "
)
```

you get:

```sh
['Page 2', 'Page 4', 'Page 6', 'Page 7', 'Page 8', 'Page 10']
```